# The cohomology of the Jacobian and its subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, hodge-theory

I read the following in a paper:

Let $G\subset J$  a subgroup of the Jacobian $J$ which is a countable  union of Zariski closed subsets in the abelian  variety $J$, so the irredundant decomposition of $G$ contains a unique irreducible component $A$ passing through $0$ which is an abelian subvariety of $J$.

Let
\begin{equation*}
   i:A\hookrightarrow J 
\end{equation*}
be the closed embedding of $A$ into $J$. Let
\begin{equation*}
    H^1(A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^1(J,\mathbb{Z})
\end{equation*}
the homomorphism in cohomology groups induced  by $i$.

My question is: how $H^1(A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^1(J,\mathbb{Z})$ is  obtained? It seems to be just the pushforward... If so, does it mean  that the  Jacobian $J$ and the irreducible component passing through $0$ of a subgroup of the Jacobian have the same  dimension?

Comment: Could you please give a link to the paper?

Comment: Why do you think something here should imply that $J$ and $A$ have the same dimension?

Comment: Dear @KBS the  paper is a more general setting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6430v2, pag 18. In this paper instead of  working  with the Jacobian $J$ they work with an Abelian variety denoted by $A$,  and to which  I am denoting by $A$ in my question  they denote  by $A_0$.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, because  the  pushforward, by definition, should be from the $1$-th cohomology of $A$ to the $(1+2r)$-th cohomology  of $J$, where $r=\dim(J)-\dim(A)$.